# A tendentious reading, based on [adjective] reasoning — what adjective?

Tags: single-word-requests, rhetoric

Let's say I quote a passage and offer a reading — or rather (according to me) *the* reading. To construct it, I employ...what?

*Motivated* reasoning?

*Interested* reasoning?

I feel like there's a clear, familiar adjective for this purpose, but it escapes me.

Not *biased.* It's something sharper, more precise.

Comment: Why doesn't "motivated reasoning" work? That's a common phrase.

Comment: Surely a *tendentious reading* derives from *tendentious reasoning*.  What need of another adjective?  Rewrite the sentence to avoid having to write *tendentious* twice, perhaps *The reviewer offers a tendentious reading of the work*.

Comment: Were you thinking of **inductive**?

Comment: You have followed some of the the information needed, by giving a model sentence.  But would you please explain you question by suggesting a specific example of the kind of reasoning you have in mind?  Without knowing at least roughly the passage or work being interpreted and the interpretation being criticised, many adjectives could fit the bill:  'speculative', 'literalistic', as well as those you mention.

Comment: @alphabet It's *motivated.* Thank you. I didn't realize I had the word.

Comment: @Graffito *partial* would be great for a different audience. My present one would read it as *incomplete.*

Comment: @Graffito Understood. However, this homonym in particular is likely to confuse my current audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented:

> Why doesn't "motivated reasoning" work? That's a common phrase.

And the asker responded:

> It's *motivated.* Thank you. I didn't realize I had the word.

It appears the matter has been resolved.

Comment: @Nafine : "substantiated" or "well-argued" are then other similar options.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use 'based on subjective reasoning' or just 'subjective':

> **subjective**: based on or influenced by personal feelings, tastes, or opinions.
>
> - *his views are highly subjective*

[[Oxford Languages; courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=subjective+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=&aqs=chrome.1.69i59i450l8.1476j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

And, from [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/subjective-vs-objective/) (excerpts):

> *Subjective* most commonly means based on the personal perspective or
> preferences of a person – the subject who’s observing something. In
> contrast, *objective* most commonly means not influenced by or based on
> a personal viewpoint – based on the analysis of an object of observation
> only.
>
> Generally speaking, *subjective* is used to describe something that
> exists in the mind of a person or that pertains to viewpoints of an
> individual person.
>
> Sometimes, *subjective* means about the same thing as *personal*.
> Everyone’s experience of an event is subjective, because each person’s
> circumstances and background are unique, leading to different
> interpretations.
>
> - *All art is subjective – everyone has their own personal interpretation*.

Answer (score 0):

**specious**, adj.

OED

> Of reasoning, arguments, etc.: Plausible, apparently sound or
> convincing, but in reality sophistical or fallacious.

> By and large, they made these changes with specious explanations or no explanation at all. Today, when curricula list rhetoric as a subject, it usually means simply the study of how to write effectively.
> *—Walter J. Ong, Orality and Literacy, (1982)* 2002

Answer (score 0):

An **opinionated** reasoning/construct.

Here is the [Merriam Webster reference](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opinionated) to it.
The link says:

> firmly or unduly adhering to one's own opinion or to preconceived notions

Example in a recent news [item](https://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/old-rich-opinionated-and-dangerous-jaishankar-hits-out-at-george-soros-101676730447027.html):

> External affairs minister S Jaishankar on Saturday accused billionaire investor George Soros of being “old, rich, opinionated and dangerous” over his controversial remarks on Prime Minister Narendra Modi and India’s democracy and called for a global debate on democratic norms.

> I could take a view that the individual in question, Mr Soros, is an old, rich, opinionated person sitting in New York who still thinks that his views should determine how the entire world works.